# How does the cluster module work in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, tcp

Can someone explain in detail how the core [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module works in Node.js?

How the workers are able to listen to a single port?

As far as I know that the master process does the listening, but how it can know which ports to listen since workers are started after the master process? Do they somehow communicate that back to the master by using the `child_process.fork` communication channel? And if so how the incoming connection to the port is passed from the master to the worker?

Also I'm wondering what logic is used to determine to which worker an incoming connection is passed?

Comment: I have a question about how the cluster module routes TCP requests. For example, I have Redis pubsub code and each and every worker in the npm cluster is receiving the messages; even while the HTTP requests are being routed to only one worker. Is there a way to configure cluster so that only one worker receives socket requests, and not all the workers? I did this myself by only having master hold the pubsub listener and then delegating manually to each of the workers. But the whole point of cluster is to do this for you out of the box...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but this is now explained at nodejs.org [here:](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works)

> The worker processes are spawned using the child_process.fork method,
>   so that they can communicate with the parent via IPC and pass server
>   handles back and forth.
>
> When you call server.listen(...) in a worker, it serializes the
>   arguments and passes the request to the master process. If the master
>   process already has a listening server matching the worker's
>   requirements, then it passes the handle to the worker. If it does not
>   already have a listening server matching that requirement, then it
>   will create one, and pass the handle to the worker.
>
> This causes potentially surprising behavior in three edge cases:
>
> server.listen({fd: 7}) - 
>   Because the message is passed to the master,
>   file descriptor 7 in the parent will be listened on, and the handle
>   passed to the worker, rather than listening to the worker's idea of
>   what the number 7 file descriptor references.
>
> server.listen(handle) - 
>   Listening on handles explicitly will cause the
>   worker to use the supplied handle, rather than talk to the master
>   process. If the worker already has the handle, then it's presumed that
>   you know what you are doing.
>
> server.listen(0) - 
>   Normally, this will cause servers to listen on a
>   random port. However, in a cluster, each worker will receive the same
>   "random" port each time they do listen(0). In essence, the port is
>   random the first time, but predictable thereafter. If you want to
>   listen on a unique port, generate a port number based on the cluster
>   worker ID.
>
> When multiple processes are all accept()ing on the same underlying
>   resource, the operating system load-balances across them very
>   efficiently. There is no routing logic in Node.js, or in your program,
>   and no shared state between the workers. Therefore, it is important to
>   design your program such that it does not rely too heavily on
>   in-memory data objects for things like sessions and login.
>
> Because workers are all separate processes, they can be killed or
>   re-spawned depending on your program's needs, without affecting other
>   workers. As long as there are some workers still alive, the server
>   will continue to accept connections. Node does not automatically
>   manage the number of workers for you, however. It is your
>   responsibility to manage the worker pool for your application's needs.

Answer (score 10):

NodeJS uses a [round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) decision to make load balancing between the child processes. It will give the incoming connections to an empty process, based on the RR algorithm.

The children and the parent do not actually share anything, the whole script is executed from the beginning to end, that is the main difference between the normal C fork. Traditional C forked child would continue executing from the instruction where it was left, not the beginning like NodeJS. So If you want to share anything, you need to connect to a cache like MemCache or Redis.

So the code below produces `6 6 6` (no evil means) on the console.

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var a = 5;
a++;
console.log(a);
if ( cluster.isMaster){
    worker = cluster.fork();
    worker = cluster.fork();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the round-robin info, but I think you misunderstood my question about the connection passing. I'm talking about the tcp connections coming to the shared port, not how to communicate between the workers.

Comment: @Epeli This discussion can be helpful to your question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/svIXu5wUXCI/discussion

Comment: I am finding that on Windows it doesn't obey Round Robin. I can spawn 10 workers and if my machine is fast enough it will throw all the incoming connections to the first worker. Any suggestions?

Comment: If first worker is empty at that moment, the work will go to it, if it is working, it will go to second one. Make a time consuming processes. The incoming connections will fall into other. Actually it is not important which one does it fall into as long as it is an empty one

Comment: Not round-robin until v0.11 http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-cluster-round-robin-load-balancing/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a  [blog post](http://onlinevillage.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-nodejs-multiprocess-load-balancing.html) that explains this

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to @OpenUserX03's answer, nodejs has no longer use system load-balances but use a built in one. from [this post](https://medium.com/@fermads/node-js-process-load-balancing-comparing-cluster-iptables-and-nginx-6746aaf38272):

> To fix that Node v0.12 got a new implementation using a round-robin algorithm to distribute the load between workers in a better way. This is the default approach Node uses since then including Node v6.0.0